# Is this mathematical induction True?

Tags: induction

I was doing a sample paper and I came across this question which is a multiple-choice question. However, upon checking the answer after I did my calculations, one of the answers had me a little confused.

---

**Question**

Consider a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$. Which of the following guarantees that "$f(n) \ge (2n)!$ for all integers $n \ge 2$" can be proved by induction?

**Given Answer**: $f(2) = 24$ and $f(k+1) \ge (2k+2)!f(k)$ for all integers $k 
\ge 2$

---

**My workings**

$f(2) \ge 2(2)$ thus, $f(2) \ge 4!$

$f(3) \ge 2(3)$ thus, $f(3) \ge 6 \times 5 \times 4!$

- Inductive step

$f(k) \ge 2k!$ thus, $f(k) \ge 2k (2k-1) (2k-1)!$

$f(k+1) \ge (2k+2)!$, therefore: $f(k+1) \ge (2k+2)(2k+1) \times f(k)$

---

According to the given answer, $f(k+1) \ge (2k+2)!f(k)$

which means $(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)! \times f(k)$

At first, I thought that this number is way too big but I'm not sure now.

Can anyone explain this to me? I'm trying to understand this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right that the answer is quite a lot bigger than it needs to be. Note that even just $f(k+1)\ge (2k+2)!$ is actually what you want (let $n=k+1$ to see this).

You did check the base case $n=2$ wrongly though. You have $f(2)=24=4!$, which is what you want.

To me, the natural answer would have been
$$
f(k+1)\ge (2k+2)(2k+1)f(k). 
$$
Then using the base case and induction we get exactly
$$f(k+1)\ge (2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!=(2k+2)!,$$
and we don’t have “too much” this time.